# Cannot add custom library in scene builder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to add a library like jfoenix-9.0.8 into scene builder (8.5.0). I am using java version 1.8.0_201 on Windows 10.

What I try in JAR/FXML Manager:
 - Search repositories
 - Manually add Libray from repository
 - Add Library/FXML from file system

What happens:
  - At begin, installed Library/FXML File list is empty
  - I choose the library
  - Import Dialog is open with no items an button "Import Jar (no UI components)

There is no error message pop up.

Comment: Using java 8 is probably a problem. jfoenix-9.* targets java 9.

Comment: Duplicated of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48841043/importing-jfoenix-library-to-scenebuilder-javafx/)

Comment: Ok that's for the Library from filesystem. Now I found the problem by using "Search repositories": it looks like, that there is using wrong version. And by using "Manually add Library from repository" the list of version is too small. So I didn't see the correct version.